# Accessing geolocation using HTML5 geolocation API in a Create React App PWA

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I've created a PWA using create-react-app that requires the [watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) functionality. Hence, when navigating to the website, it asks ' wants to know your location' and after giving permission, I can monitor the user's location as anticipated.
However, once I click on 'Add to Home Screen', the user's location this functionality does not work. The application does not ask for the user's permission for location updates. Is there a way to enable location tracking using create-react-app in offline mode?